# Convert array of coordinates to google.maps.LatLng array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm getting the following error by trying to create a google.maps.LatLng array:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined
```

Here's what I'm doing:

I am dynamically populating a bi-dimensional array of GPS coordinates, like this:

```
const array = [
    [1.23123, -1.23123],
    [4.56456, -4.56456],
    [7.89789, -7.89789]
]
```

Which I'm trying to convert to a google.maps.LatLng array by doing the following:

```
const latLngArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  latLngArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(array[i][0], array[i][1]));
}
```

And then assigning it to my new HeatmapLayer like this:

```
this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: latLngArray,
  map: this.map
});
```

The map loads just fine, but the points related to the coordinates don't (and I'm getting that error).

But if I manually create the following function and assign it to the data field in the HeatmapLayer it works:

```
getPoints() {
    return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(1.23123, -1.23123),
      new google.maps.LatLng(4.56456, -4.56456),
      new google.maps.LatLng(7.89789, -7.89789)
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to `push()` i.e it should be `latLngArray.push(...)`

Comment: Sorry I miscopied that. I am pushing it in my code (I will edit the question)

Comment: is array is consist of any string values or its just numbers ?

Comment: The posted code works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/805eqdt1/1/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: It turns out the problem was somewhere else. The current code works properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like....

```
let latLngArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const gData = new google.maps.LatLng(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
  latLngArray.push(gData);
}
```